# textview invisible in horizontal scrollview during scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

whenever i scroll horizontalScrollbar it invisible or blink the textview that are not currently visible on screen.

```
| element 1 | element 2 | element 3 | element 4 | element 5 |
                            ------> | element 4 | element 5 | 

element 4 and element 5 get blink and invisible during scroll
```

any suggestion ???

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

surround your view with co-ordinate layout 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html

Comment: thanks but don't want to use co-ordinate layout @AshishRawat